# How exactly does the VirtoCommerce platform work for building a custom website?

Tags: e-commerce, virtocommerce

I am new to working with a CMS-platform and building an ecommerce website so please bear with me if my questions aren't spot on..

While I understand the concept behind a CMS-platform, I am trying to understand how I can build a custom website using the Liquid Theme Engine and VC. I have the platform and storefront both up and running locally (the electronics example store), and have even played around with extending a model and generating the new API endpoints for it(adding a wishlist type to the shopping cart) - this part is cool, I understand this is how the data is accessed.

However Liquid is new to me and I have a little understanding of how Angular works but not in a platform framework like VC, and Google searches are diluted with Shopify documentation which doesn't help me understand how a Liquid Theme fits into VC. If I spend the time to understand Liquid more, is my end goal to build a website theme in Liquid, and then reference that in the platform as the websites theme?

Are there any resources out there, besides what is listed on the VC website that could help connect the dots for me? (I think I've tried all the documents on the VC site and there are a lot of missing gaps)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the questions exactly you have? We have a [large readme file](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-theme-default) for default theme. Also, [here](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/working-with-storefront/theme-development) is a link to our docs about theme development. This topics describe theme structure, bundling & minification, localization and liquid language reference. Here is also a little explanation how theme work:

- In Storefront, you have Controllers, which return View
- ASP.NET view is template in Shopify terms. So LiquidThemeEngine try find this view in templates folder
- Template may include snippets from snippets folder
- Template have layout (usually header, body & footer) from layout folder (theme.liquid is default layout)
- Templates and snippets may include angular components & controllers from assets/js folder and other static files (like images required by theme design) in root of assets or subfolder.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and sorry for my delay in getting back to you - I've reviewed the readme on the default theme, and it is starting to make a little more sense. Do you know if it is possible to modify or change the sample storefronts, like the Electronics store? If I were able to create a 'hello world' page, I think it would help me out more but I am not able to locate where the pages for these stores are defined - the cms-content folder does not contain a pages directory like the readme lays out.

Thanks

Comment: So I've followed the entire README you pointed me to, but it does not explain much about how to achieve the structure of the diagram shown in the README, how to apply it to an existing store, or anything else really useful for a beginner.. I am trying to create a new store from scratch using the default theme as a starting point, and I have all the folders shown in the diagram with only a very simple "hello world" page in the pages folder - but I get 403 errors when I try to preview the store. Any advice here? Thanks

Comment: Alright I believe I've got it figured out now - my lack of knowledge/understanding around Angular and Liquid was the cause of the confusion. Getting this platform up and running as a beginner is a bit challenging! Thanks for the help.